# asp.net mvc published how can ı save file in iss server and how can fınd thisfolder path

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, publish, plesk

[image]Im writing a asp.net mvc project it basically create excess and save server im try to do that and its work on my local like this gif user set 2 dates and ım fılter my db sources using this two date and after that ım create excel files and save in folder "Reports" it's perfectly work in my local but its doesn't work published folder doesn't have report folder and ıf ım try create excel in iss its created but ı dont know its saved or if saved save where? [image]

Im save my my excel files like this

```
 string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), ("Reports\\" + name));

                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(path);//new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\amir\Desktop\test.xlsx");
                excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
```

and its donsnt work in Release dont save this files in this folder also this folder(Reports) does not exist and also ım create manually but ıts donst work

after that ım take error from my download function like this

```
Could not find file 'G:\PleskVhosts\ngsdev.net\httpdocs\Reports\Report_1_1_2020-2-19-04_PM.xls'.
```

so i try to change my path like this

```
string path = "G:\\PleskVhosts\\ngsdev.net\\httpdocs\\Reports\\" + name;
```

and its doesn't work so how can ı do this like my locally any idea or solution is welcomed thanks for help.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you publish your application to the IIS? What's your folder structure about this web application? Do you face any error when you save the excels files?

Comment: Im try to save in iss my reports directory but ıts cant be exist its my problems.I can save files in my locally but ıcant save in ııs  its my problem ım try tu right click reports and  Publish Reports but its dosnt work if you want to see all project ı can upload github and share with you thx for help

Comment: Since all the codes is working well in your local side, there is no need to upload the whole application to the GitHub. I want to know the details error message when you click the save button after you have hosted the application on the IIS. I guess there must be some error like permission or path error. So I want to know the folder structure about this web application when you hosted the application on the IIS and I suggest you could check the event viewer to see if there is some useful error message in it .